# android autocomplete dropdown overlay on custom keyboard

Tags: java, android, xml

I created a custom keyboard but when i search in autocomplete, dropdown overlay on custom keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting autocomplete drop down height according to height of custom keyboard. Thanx